# Can boilerplatejs be made to work with IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, boilerplatejs

I would like to utilize [boilerplatejs](http://boilerplatejs.org) for an upcoming intranet project, however, many of the machines are still WinXP with IE8 (and there's no option in the orginazation for wide-scale Firefox or Chrome deployment).

I've quickly tried incorporating the html5shiv, but that didn't seem to help.  It doesn't appear routing or other functionality is working.  I'm trying to figure out if this is even worth doing or if someone else has tried to get this working before spending more time on it.

Comment: I have successfully adapted *boilerplatejs* to work with IE8 in a complex application, so I can confirm this is not a limit.

If you posted specific error message you get, it would help to answer your question.

Comment: Stas's changes are now merged in to main BoileplateJS repository. Now onward it should be working fine with IE 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoilerplateJS core is not designed with any HTML5 features. Though I haven't tested it in IE8, I believe this is very much possible with some adjustments. For example, if crossroadsJS, the library used for routing is not compatible with IE8, still you may easily replace that with pathJS or something else that is IE8 compatible.

Comment: My cursory glance at BoilerplateJS core seemed to indicate this.  I hadn't thought of just dealing with the offending libraries, but that is easy enough in BoilerplateJS for me to continue down this path.  That's one of the reasons I enjoy using BoilerplateJS!

Comment: Tell us if u do any improvements. We may merge such to the mainstream code base!

Answer (score 2):

Not really. That's what the code in h5bp is about

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Those are conditional clauses for graceful degradation of ie < 9.

If this is a project where many people will be on ie<9, it might be better to use xhtml...just an engineering consideration

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the most difficult problems you'll encounter are not about *boilerplatejs* but external libraries.

Specific tweaks depend on the features you leverage in your application, but for a start all you need to to is to

- add *html5shim* to support HTML5 elements like `<section>`
- include *json2* library for missing json serialization support
- [optionally] include [*explorercanvas*](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) to enable *flot* charting

Put this inside your `<head>` section:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

With this snippet you'll get *boilerplatejs* example page working, with routing, themes and i18n support.

Then, you'll notice that in the *Click Counter* example you don't win regardless how many times you click on the button. This is because `LOTTERY_ACTIVITY` event published by *clickCounter/clickme* component doesn't reach any listeners due to a bug(?) in *pubsub.js* library (I even [submitted an issue](https://github.com/federico-lox/pubsub.js/issues/10#issuecomment-10878509) some time ago). To resolve it, patch *libs\pubsub\pubsub-20120708.js*, changing

```
params = (args.length > 1) ? Array.prototype.splice.call(args, 1) : []
```

to IE8-compatible call:

```
params = (args.length > 1) ? Array.prototype.splice.call(args, 1, args.length-1) : []
```

Congratulations... You WON!!!

I leave fixing remaining issues in the *Backbone TODO* module up to you, you may use the [original code](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/) as a guidance.

To summarize, I would say that ***boilerplatejs* is fully IE8-compatible**, with any incompatibilities coming from supporting libraries, not the core code.

Comment: wow.. this is cool work.. thanks for the help.. I will pull it!